# Convert datetime int to datetime

Tags: php, date, datetime, format

I pulled data from a website and I get the following datetime : `1379782800000`. When I check the website the date should be `21-09-2013`. But how can I get the date of the datetime int given? I need the date in a proper format to compare it with the current datetime and to show it to the user.

Comment: Use the [`date`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Comment: That appears to be a javascript timestamp, which is simply milliseconds since the epoch, +/- timezone.

Comment: You shouldn't need any format for the comparison. You can compare integer timestamps. Also, can you be more specific about what you are trying to show the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking at (the big number) is a timestamp. The timestamp is the amount of seconds since the 1st of january 1970 till the moment the timestamp was set.

To "calculate" a date you can use the php [date function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
echo date('d-m-Y', 1379782800);
```

will show you your date in the right format.
Keep in mind your timestamp is too long.

For comparison, you can better use the timestamp (integer comparisson is faster and more accurate then string comparison)

Comment: I don't think that's [quite right](http://3v4l.org/pQPDD).

Comment: You need to [divide by 1000](http://3v4l.org/LZK7H)

Comment: @vascowhite I corrected my reaction